# Is there another way of routing in React-JS/React-TS beyonds the library react-router-dom@latest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a frontend project.

I need to set the net of routes.

I've found that there the react-router-dom@latest.

I'd like to know if there's another option.

Because, JS a opensouce.

So I thought someone else could've created another to route.

Comment: is there a feature missing?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly urge you to go with the `react-router-dom`. but, still as far as I know, You can go with these 2 alternatives:

=> **Reach Router:**

Reach Router: Reach Router is a routing library that mainly focuses on accessibility. Reach Router aims to provide a simpler and more predictable routing experience but still in the experimental phase.

Here are the few links you can explore:

1. Official Documentation: https://reach.tech/router/
2. https://github.com/reach/router/tree/d2c9ad06715c9d48c2d16f55f7cd889b626d2521/website/src/markdown
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reach/router

=> Second alternative is you can start using Next.js which is built on top of ReactJS and includes built-in routing capabilities. It provides an easy-to-use file-based routing system, where each page is represented by a React component.

Answer (score 1):

React-router-dom was recommended officially by React JS which why it is the most commonly used package. You can explore more packages at https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:routing. For example there is a package called [react-easy-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-easy-router) which is being used by many people too. So I guess there is no limitation on the routing packages for React, and there is no guarantee that react-router-dom is the easiest package out there. There might be more simpler packages too, its just that people are more comfortable using it.